# Change theme when OS dark mode changes?

Tags: osx, themes

VS Code recently added the ability to switch themes when macOS's dark mode changes. Presumably they use the Electron API, which internally uses the Objective-C API of subscribing to the `AppleInterfaceThemeChangedNotification` event in `NSDistributedNotificationCenter`.

It would be nice if Emacs had this same ability. The pseudo-code would be:

```
(add-event 'os-dark-mode-changed
  (lambda (on)
    (set-theme (if on
                  some-dark-theme
                  some-light-theme))))
```

(In VS Code, the dark and light themes are configurable.)

Does Emacs have the ability to do something similar?

Comment: Maybe you can periodically [query the dark mode status](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25214873/605276).

Comment: Then I'd have to poll, whereas macOS already provides an event for this. There was a reddit thread on this solution and it was generally thought of as being bad practice.

Comment: I’ve [submitted a patch which provides an `ns-dark-mode-change-hook`](https://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/emacs-devel/2021-03/msg00482.html) which you could use to do this. Hopefully it will be accepted, and then a future version of Emacs will have this feature!

Answer (score 2):

Using [emacs-plus](https://github.com/d12frosted/homebrew-emacs-plus) this is easy. See [the docs](https://github.com/d12frosted/homebrew-emacs-plus#system-appearance-change), but here is the code in any case.

```
(defun my/apply-theme (appearance)
  "Load theme, taking current system APPEARANCE into consideration."
  (mapc #'disable-theme custom-enabled-themes)
  (pcase appearance
    ('light (load-theme 'tango t))
    ('dark (load-theme 'tango-dark t))))

(add-hook 'ns-system-appearance-change-functions #'my/apply-theme)
```

Answer (score 0):

A work-around, more so than an answer: you can change your theme from an external process, by starting your main editor instance in server mode, and using `emacsclient`. E.g.

```lisp
(server-start)
```

And:

```sh
emacsclient --eval "(my/dark-mode)" --quiet -no-wait --suppress-output -a true
```

It turns out that iTerm2 allows you to execute an arbitrary Python script on OS theme changes. You can use this to change iTerm2's *own* theme, but nothing stops you from adding a cheeky call to `emacsclient` and controlling Emacs along, with it.

I've combined all of this here: https://gist.github.com/hraban/8eb4ab5c110828a9d1b8c16b4f78193e.

Upside: no polling, no Emacs UI blocking, etc

Downside: iTerm2 must be running.